# What happens if my second year visa gets refused while I am in New Zealand and have no money for a flight out of the country?

Tags: new-zealand, overstay

I am currently waiting on my partner to receive his next visa, my first year working holiday visa for New Zealand will be up in march, when he receives his I am going to apply for a de facto visa/partnership visa but what happens if it gets refused and I have no savings for a flight back to my country ?

We have spoken to an immigration agent who told me not to apply for my visa until my partner receives his, so we are still currently waiting, his is still being processed so fingers crossed it will be any day now.

I am just worried that mine will be refused and I have no savings to afford a flight out of here, can anyone suggest what to do if this does happen?

Comment: I suspect that the NZ government will buy you a flight home, via a deportation procedure, with associated impact on future visa prospects for most major countries...

Answer (score 3):

You should contact *your* embassy or consulate in the host country. One of the jobs of the consular staff is to help their citizens when they are in trouble. The embassy might extend a loan to buy a ticket home. (At least European nations do that, you didn't mention where you come from.)

If and how they will help depends on the circumstances, and your government will do its best to get the money back once you're home. So you'd be in debt, but without the overstay on your record.